# Python, is there a way to assign df.drop to a new variable?

Tags: python, pandas

I've been practicing python for a while now and just got into pandas to start learning dataframes. I understand that df.drop() will remove a column/row based on certain requirements and makes a new df. I was wondering, is there a way to assign those dropped columns/rows to a new variable for logging purposes?

```
import pandas as pd
L = ["a","b","c","d","a","a"]
df1 = pd.DataFrame(L)
df1.columns = ['letter']
#print(df1)

df2 = df1.drop(df1.letter == "a", axis=0)
print(df2)

 letter
2      c
3      d
4      a #why is this row not removed?
5      a #why is this row not removed?
```

However, this doesn't even print a new df2 where all the rows with "a" are removed (separate problem here not sure why that is happening).

Assigning the removed column to a new df doesn't work because it is using the initial dataframe df1. I am just unsure of how to make two dataframes, one with ONLY the removed columns and one where the removed columns are edited out.

I would want a df3 that prints:

```
letter
0      a
4      a
5      a
```

Comment: df3=df1.loc[df1.letter=='a',:]

Comment: Thank you!!! I also realized that df2 = df[df.letter != "a"] returns my df2 without the "a" rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a mask for your condition.  Select the rows to be removed based on the condition using boolean indexing.  Then reassign `df1` to by inverting the mask using `~` (not).

```
mask = df1['letter'] == 'a'
removed_rows = df1[mask]
df1 = df1[~mask]

>>> df1
  letter
1      b
2      c
3      d

>>> removed_rows
  letter
0      a
4      a
5      a
```

Comment: How do you create a mask when you need to drop columns using a for loop My condition is not set to a letter but rather a few calculations that determines the column to drop. I want to keep those dropped columns as a separate dataframe for comparison. Not sure how to implement mask for this. Don't even know where to start with that one.

Comment: @DNAngel In general, it is best to avoid `for` loops when working with pandas dataframes.  Perhaps you can ask another question providing the minimal information to create what you are trying to achieve (https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve & https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples).

Answer (score 2):

I would just select the specific rows before dropping them:

```
df2 = df1.loc[df1.letter == "a"]
```

Comment: I notice that this works without using loc, so df1[df1.letter == 'a'] also works. Is there a reason I need to use loc? Would there be unforeseen issues down the road?

Comment: It seems that this is just for clarity. Because explicity is better to get than implicity in code.